# Any easy way of combining two UITableViewControllers into one, with each being its own section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've inherited an existing project, and right now I'm looking at a scene that has a pair of UITableViews on it, each with their own controller... and we've determined that it would be a better user experience if they were a single table with two sections in it.  The data sources are completely different, but I think this makes sense anyway because of how the user is likely to interact with the data.

ANYWAY, so now I've got FooTableViewController, and I've got BarTableViewController, and I need to come up with a FooAndBarTableViewController.  The best solution I can come up with is to inherit from FooTableViewController, and override a bunch of methods with something along the lines of:

```
-(Yada*) someMethod:(BlahBlah *)blahBlah {
  if( section == 0 ) {
    return [super someMethod:blahBlah]
  }
  else {
    //copy-paste stuff from BarTableViewController
  }
}
```

Which, as long as BarTableViewController is not tremendously complex, doesn't seem too awfully bad.  But there's still some Repeating Yourself going on here that I'm not crazy about.

Anybody got any better ideas?

Comment: I don't really understand the situation to be honest... why not use one controller that has both table views in it? you can then still implement the `dataSource` objects each in separate files.

Comment: At the end of the day, I want there to be a single UITableView... with two sections, that used to each be their own UITableView.

Comment: can't you put the data from both data sources into the same `dataSource` object that will serve as `dataSource` for your new, merged table view? then in your data source methods you fetch the appropriate value...

Comment: i think nburk means to combine the datasources/delegates into a single uitableviewcontroller datasource/delegate. if the two controllers aren't thousands of lines long, it's worth it to refactor and pull in the relevant code. write a new cellForRowAtIndexPath: and put the logic for both old cellForRowAtIndexPath: methods into it, etc. for numberOfRowsInSection just use the old numberOfRowsInSection but now you have two sections.

Comment: One of the controllers has an inheritance chain about a mile long... that makes it difficult to get a handle on just how much effort I'd be looking at in any potential refactoring.

Comment: Heh, so I've been going down the inherit-from-one-copy-from-the-other method I suggested in my question... and it sucks.  I am pretty sure I can make it work, but the guy after me is going to crap his pants.  Totally unmaintainable.   TBH, I think the ultimate answer to this question is along the lines of what nburk is suggesting, except that to do that will require that I detangle a lot of existing messes in this project.  Blah...

Comment: TL;DR: No, there's not an easy way.  At least not that I can see.  The method I suggested previously would probably work to combine very simple controllers, but then why not just redo it so they are single controller to begin with?  And if the controllers are really complicated, then trying to do it the easy way is going to be a never-ending rabbit hole.  Answer: Refactor.  Im doin it rong.

Answer (score 0):

An important detail I didn't mention is that the two tables to be combined had different entities.  That makes the whole mess even harder.  You *can* do that with a single UITableViewController, but it makes it a lot less straightforward to rely on e.g. NSFetchedResultsControllers and such.

But I finally hit on an "easy way": Put both tables in a UIScrollView, and size them to be their content height.  You lose some of the nice behavior with the section headers, but for the amount of time this is going to save me, it's worth it.